# Scaffold-DbContext to dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold convertion

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, dotnet-tool

I have a hard time finding the syntax for this in .NET EF world

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=server_dns,sql_port;Database=db-name; User ID=sql-account;Password=LeetPa$$w0rd;" -StartupProject Solution.Api Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Context ApiDbContext -ContextDir "Data\Context" -OutputDir "..\Solution.Api.Data.Entities\CRL" -Namespace "Solution.Api.Data.Entities.CRL" -ContextNamespace "Solution.Api.Data.Context" -NoOnConfiguring -Force
```

This is what I got so far:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=server_dns,sql_port;Database=db-name; User ID=sql-account;Password=LeetPa$$w0rd;" -StartupProject Solution.Api Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --context ApiDbContext --context-dir "Data\Context" --output-dir "..\Solution.Api.Data.Entities\DBStuff" -Namespace "Solution.Api.Data.Entities.CRL" -ContextNamespace "Solution.Api.Data.Context" -NoOnConfiguring -Force
```

> Failed on Unrecognized option '-StartupProject'

Comment: For the `dotnet` command line I would imagine that's meant to be `--startup-project` with double dashes at the beginning. Have you run `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold --help` yet?

Comment: Consult the [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) to find out about all the supported options and command line switches. ...

Comment: Did you try the first example in Package Manager Console in VS ?

Comment: I ok with  Package Manager Console as long as I'm using VS2022. I had to shift to an ad-hoc VM with just VSCode and needed to scaffold in terminal